# Intellij Idea template highlited in yellow

Tags: templates, intellij-idea

When I create a new class file it is created with default template.
Why is it highlited with yellow color? Does it just mean "hey look, I am template!"? Why does it look like some grammar/spellcheck highlite style?
[image: template highlited]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means "Hey look, I'm the **default** template still".  If you alter the template, then create a new class, it will no longer be highlighted as yellow.  It will be highlighted like a normal comment.